# How do I override an Entity Type's label in Symfony 2 with multiple field values?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I'm trying to make a custom form in Symfony 2. I've got a Entity field type that I'm trying to render as expanded / multiple. The default rendering for each entity is something like the following pseudo code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value='$entity->id'><label>$entity->id</label>
```

This is pretty terrible. I'd like to get symfony to render each entity with something more detailed like:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value='$entity->id'><label><strong>$entity->name</strong>
    <div>$entity->detail</div></label>
</div>
```

The documentation doesn't mention how to access specific fields of an entity when rendering a form. Does anyone have an idea of how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you are trying to customize form rendering, for that just follow documentation - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Basically yes, technically no.  The documentation doesn't cover how to render an entity field separately from the entity widget.  Plus the link you added, doesn't cover entity types at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can access specific fields on an entity like this - `{{ form_widget(form.your_choice_field.0) }}` for the first item, `{{ form_widget(form.your_choice_field.1) }}` for the second and so on.

`your_choice_field` is a form field, which could be `choice` or `entity`.

`{{ form_widget(form.your_choice_field.0) }}` allows you to access individual items in `choices` array.

Comment: This would be useful, but I'm having trouble getting it working. Should it be `form_widget` instead of `form.widget`? Then, can you be more explicit about what "your_entity" is?  Is that the entity name? The name of the entity field?  Lets say I have a "Priority" entity with my entity field type called "priorities".

Answer (score 1):

The default layout for all forms, if you use the full stack framework, is placed in

```
vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig
```

you can see what happens there which is that entity is rendered as

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        {{ form_widget(child) }}
        {{ form_label(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

if you want to owerwrite rendering of a row of an entity field, as @Manocho mentioned, you can refer to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html and overwrite that block in your template file and then add

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

so twig will search for overwritten blocks in the same twig file it is rendered in

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `property` option when adding your `entity` field as [described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property)? You can also add `__toString` method to your entity.

Comment: This neatly accomplishes half of what I need, and the rest a little more ugly.  I'm hoping I can get what @dmnptr answered with for the other half. The two together make a fairly elegant solution.